# Is there no way to prevent gvim from reading the system wide menu file?

Tags: vimrc, startup

When I start gvim without rc file (`gvim -i NONE -u NONE -U NONE`), gvim still reads `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim`. I am looking for a way to prevent gvim from doing exactly that.

In fact, `:help -U` explicitely states

```
-U {gvimrc} [...]
        Exception: Reading the system-wide menu file is always done.
        [...]
```

Do I have to interpret this *exception* such that there is really no way to start gvim without the menu.vim?

Comment: I just make the file empty on packaging Vim (removing it causes errors). But now opened [`:help menu.vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#menu.vim) and it mentions `:let did_install_default_menus = 1` and `:let did_install_syntax_menu = 1`, did you try setting them?

Comment: In order to set these variables, I'd need an rc file to assign the respective values. But, by using `-U NONE` and `-u NONE` I explicitely state to not use any rc file

Comment: You can try setting them via `--cmd` (not `-c` or `+` probably) command-line switch.

Comment: This did indeed do the trick. But I am still having the illusion, that there is a more easy way for this.

Comment: `:help 'guioptions'`

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent loading the menu by setting the `'go'` option.

Excerpt from my .vimrc:

```
" don't want any menus, just an term like gvim
" needs to come first, because :syn on and :filetype
" would else load the system menu
set go=M
```

Comment: You might want to add the `--cmd` thingy so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: I think the reader can figure it out by themselves :)

Comment: I for one couldn't.

Comment: I don't understand. You know `--cmd` and you know the option name and setting. What exactly do you have problems with finding out?

Comment: I believe the OP means that they *didn't* know about the `--cmd` option when they first read your answer, and thus couldn't figure out how to apply the change until someone else told them about the `--cmd` option. Therefore, they believe having it in the answer would be helpful (not to solve their problem, but for future readers).

Comment: Well, whatever, I mentioned the proper option setting and value, so it should be marked solved.